# Установочный SQL файл в JOOMLA

Tags: joomla, sql

Создаю файл install.sql. В нем пишу команду

```
CREATE TABLE `hi` (`id_r` int(11),`id` int(11),`file` varchar(255),`mini` varchar(255),`homename` varchar(255),`size` varchar(255),`var` varchar(255),`count` varchar(255),`comment` varchar(255),`client_name` varchar(255),`client_phone` varchar(255),`client_addr` varchar(255)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Сохраняю файл в utf-8, в установочном xml файле прописываю

```
 <install>
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql">install.sql</file>
    </sql>
  </install>
```

Устанавливаю компонент, в базе данных никакой новой таблицы не появляется. Пишет, что всё нормально установлено.

Answer (score 1):

Я этой штуке вообще не доверяю, в инсталляторе из пхп все писал, когда компонент делал.

А в админке можно вывести кнопку типа "Хотите удалить - эта кнопка удалит все таблицы компонента".

Да, это неправильно, но работает)

Comment: так и сделаю))